# How to use c++98 without gnu extensions in cmake >= 2.6?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have to support cmake 2.6 at least (and latest versions like 3.12 too):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
```

And want to specify the old c++ standard (c++98) and forbid gnu extensions (use -std=c++98 instead of -std=gnu++98). In newer versions (since 3.0) we have [CXX_EXTENSIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html) and [CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html), but I can't use them because cmake 2.6 doesn't support them.

I tried to specify `add_definitions(-std=c++98)`, but it causes compile string like this:

```
/usr/bin/c++ ..... -std=c++98 ..... -std=gnu++98 .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always set (or modify) `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`  to `-std=c++98` to overrule what CMake sets on its own.